# Salvar variavél na struct por ponteiro

Tags: c, struct

estou com um problema no meu código que não consigo resolver, creio que seja um detalhe simples, mas que até agora não descobri.

Preciso passar por referencia um vetor, que possui uma struct, porem ele não está alocando os dados na struct e o programa fecha.

Esse aqui é uma das funções:

```
    void cadastProd(Produto *cP) {
    system("cls");

    arquivo = fopen(PRO,"a+");
    printf("\n|************************************************|");
    printf("\n|*              CADASTRAR PRODUTO               *|");
    printf("\n|************************************************|");

    printf("\n\n  Informe o numero de produtos: ");
    scanf("%d",&q);
    for(i=0; i<q; i++) {
        (*cP).codigo[i] = i+1; // Codigo do Produto
        fflush(stdin);
        printf("\n  Nome do Produto: ");
        scanf(" %[^\n]s", &cP->nome[i]);
        printf("\n  Valor do Produto: ");
        scanf("%f", &cP->valor[i]);
        printf("\n  ");
        printf("%d - %s - R$%.2f\n", cP->codigo[i], cP->nome[i], cP->valor[i]);
        fprintf(arquivo,"%d - %s - R$%.2f\n", cP->codigo[i], cP->nome[i], cP->valor[i]);
    }
    fclose(arquivo);{
}
```

A struct dessa função é essa aqui:

```
    typedef struct produto {
    char codigo[30];
    char nome[30];
    float valor[30];
} Produto;
```

Gostaria de uma ajuda sobre o que posso estar errando. Obrigado

Comment: Como é chamada a função `cadastProd` ?

Comment: Chamo ela por um switch case, direto no main.

    cadastProd();
    break;

Comment: Mas passando o que como parametro ? E como foi inicializado o que é passado ?

Comment: Quando eu chamo a função no main, eu não passei parametro algum, apenas na função. Fiz um ponteiro para o struct.

Comment: Se você usa o parametro dentro da função como sendo algo válido mas não passa nada não tem como funcionar. Já para não falar que mesmo que passa-se alguma coisa a utilização também não faz sentido, o `(*cP).codigo[i]`. Mas no fim é dificil de ajudar sem saber exatamente o que você está a tentar fazer

Comment: Eu preciso que cada função receba do usuário valor para ser inserido numa struct. Sendo que nessa struct os dados precisam ser salvos em um arquivo. Não sei se ficou claro.

Comment: Sem ver o código que você usa para chamar é dificil de ajudar